# Conditionally sending an object of key-value (array) from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to pass an object of key-value pairs with the value being an array of strings from a Child component to a Parent's state. These values will come from UI-Kitten's multi-select component and it'll be passed as an object to the Parent.

I understand how passing of data works between parent and child components and the usage of `useEffect` in a component for `componentDidMount` or any conditional fires of an effect. But this case is rather complex.

I could possibly dump the entire Child component into the Parent as I have tried replicating something similar and it works i.e. I get the object of key-value pairs updated whenever user selects/deselects an option from the multi-select. Hoping that I could take the Child-Parent so the Parent wouldn't clutter up as the Child component is pretty long.

I hope I could get some help with it. Thank you!

**Parent Component** (the state, technologyExperience, is not updating):

```js
  const [technologyExperience, setTechnologyExperience] = React.useState({
    game: [],
    web: [],
    mobile: [],
    database: [],
    machineLearning: []
  });

  const getSelections = data => {
    setTechnologyExperience(prevData => {
      return { ...prevData, ...data };
    });

    // Only prints on first load
    console.log('parent.getSelections', technologyExperience);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Only prints on first load
    console.log('parent.useEffect.getSelections', technologyExperience);
  }, [getSelections]);


// calling of the Child component
<InputBackgroundSelect getSelections={getSelections} />
```

**Child component**:

```js
const InputBackgroundSelect = props => {
  // All the values needed to pass to Parent
  const [gameIndex, setGameIndex] = React.useState([]);
  const displayGameDev = gameIndex.map(index => {
    return gameDevData[index.row];
  });

  const [webIndex, setWebIndex] = React.useState([]);
  const displayWebDev = webIndex.map(index => {
    return webDevData[index.row];
  });

  const [mobileIndex, setMobileIndex] = React.useState([]);
  const displaymobileDev = mobileIndex.map(index => {
    return mobileDevData[index.row];
  });

  const [dbIndex, setDBIndex] = React.useState([]);
  const displayDb = dbIndex.map(index => {
    return dbData[index.row];
  });

  const [mlIndex, setMLIndex] = React.useState([]);
  const displayMl = mlIndex.map(index => {
    return mlData[index.row];
  });

  // As for the conditional effect, I have tried using
  // [displayGameDev, displayWebDev, displaymobileDev, displayDb, displayMl] too.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Only prints on first load but not when selecting/deselecting options
    console.log('Calling props.getSelections'); 

    props.getSelections({
      game: displayGameDev,
      web: displayWebDev,
      mobile: displaymobileDev,
      database: displayDb,
      machineLearning: displayMl
    });
  }, [setGameIndex, setWebIndex, setMobileIndex, setDBIndex, setMLIndex]);

// An example of the 5 repeated Selects
      <Select
        label='Mobile Development'
        style={styles.selectInput}
        multiSelect={true}
        selectedIndex={mobileIndex}
        onSelect={index => setMobileIndex(index)} // Fires when user selects an option from the Select
        placeholder='Select'
        value={displaymobileDev.join(', ')}
      >
        {mobileDevData.map((value, key) => (
          <SelectItem key={key} title={value} />
        ))}
      </Select>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you at least see the updated `technologyExperience` when the `useEffect` fires in the parent? BTW, you've the wrong dependency for that effect, it should be `technologyExperience`.

Comment: @DrewReese : if using the codes in this question, it's not printing. Only prints on first load.  I've changed the dependency to `technologyExperience`, to no avail too.

Comment: Have you verified that `getSelections` in the parent is being called? If you drop a console log there before the state update do you see the log? Do you see the log *after* the enqueued state update?

Comment: apparently, `getSelections` only called once when the screen is shown, likewise the other 2 `useEffect` declarations. i've updated the codes above for better illustration. 

Verified that `getSelections` in the parent is only called once when screen shown.
Before state updates, yes i see the logs `parent.getSelections ...` and `parent.useEffect.getSelections ...`

No, i do not see the log after the enqueued state update

Comment: Fix the `useEffect` dependencies in the child so the effect can actually run correctly. You seem to have a misunderstanding on what the React hook dependencies are. Do you *actually* update any state in the child *other* than `mobileIndex`?

Comment: noted, i'll try that out now! i just want to add that i actually placed `props.getSelections` into a function `const unsubscribe = () => props.getSelections` and did `return () => unsubscribe()` in the useEffect function earlier and it prints. but the Parent doesn't receive the updated data.

Comment: yes sir. i have 4 other states updating too. `mobileIndex, aIndex, bIndex, etc`. i'll add the codes in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232936/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-domster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

It seems the bulk of your issue here is a misunderstanding of React hook dependencies. You are using the state updater function as the dependency, but these are stable references, i.e. they are the same from render to render, so if included in a hook's dependency array they won't trigger the hook callback.

[useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

> **Note**
>
> React guarantees that `setState` function identity is stable and won’t
> change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the
> `useEffect` or `useCallback` dependency list.

You will see the `useEffect` callback called once on the initial render, but since the dependencies are stable they are never updated and will never trigger the effect callback again later.

**Additional Issues**

Within the `InputBackgroundSelect` component the `displayGameDev, displayWebDev, displaymobileDev, displayDb, displayMl, getSelections` variables are dependencies for the `useEffect` for the `getSelections` callback, ***but*** they are declared in the function body of the component. This means they are redeclared each render cycle, thus triggering some render looping.

## Solution

Fix the `useEffect` dependencies in both the parent and child component. Hook dependencies are basically anything that is referenced within the callback that make change from render to render.

Parent

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log('parent.useEffect.getSelections', technologyExperience);
}, [technologyExperience]);
```

Child

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  getSelections({
    game: displayGameDev,
    web: displayWebDev,
    mobile: displaymobileDev,
    database: displayDb,
    machineLearning: displayMl
  });
}, [displayGameDev, displayWebDev, displaymobileDev, displayDb, displayMl, getSelections]);
```

Additional note about React state updates, they are asynchronous, so you can't console log your state *right after* enqueueing an update, it'll still only be the state value from the *current* render cycle, not what you just enqueued for the *next* render.

```
const getSelections = data => {
  setTechnologyExperience(prevData => {
    return { ...prevData, ...data };
  });

  // This will be current state, not next state
  console.log('parent.getSelections', technologyExperience);
};
```

Just use the `useEffect with dependency on` technologyExperience` to log when it updates. (*i.e. the issue fixed above* )

To fix the render looping you need to memoize both the `getSelections` callback with `useCallback`.

```
const getSelections = React.useCallback(data => {
  setTechnologyExperience(prevData => ({ ...prevData, ...data }));
}, []);
```

And the `displayGameDev, displayWebDev, displaymobileDev, displayDb, displayMl` listed here with `useMemo`.

```
const [gameIndex, setGameIndex] = React.useState([]);
const displayGameDev = React.useMemo(
  () => gameIndex.map((index) => gameDevData[index.row]),
  [gameIndex]
);

const [webIndex, setWebIndex] = React.useState([]);
const displayWebDev = React.useMemo(
  () => webIndex.map((index) => webDevData[index.row]),
  [webIndex]
);

const [mobileIndex, setMobileIndex] = React.useState([]);
const displaymobileDev = React.useMemo(
  () => mobileIndex.map((index) => mobileDevData[index.row]),
  [mobileIndex]
);

const [dbIndex, setDBIndex] = React.useState([]);
const displayDb = React.useMemo(
  () => dbIndex.map((index) => dbData[index.row]),
  [dbIndex]
);

const [mlIndex, setMLIndex] = React.useState([]);
const displayMl = React.useMemo(
  () => mlIndex.map((index) => mlData[index.row]),
  [mlIndex]
);
```

Here's a link to a forked [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@drew.w.reese/b71d99).